# Using drony to enable system wide ABP

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, proxy

I am trying to get system wide adblock set up on android 5.1. After setting up the proxy as asked in was told that it would only work on the default "internet" browser. After further research I found that this could be done with drony but after trying I have had no luck (with ABP and Drony enabled) wondering if anyone could help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to block ads on android through the hosts file rather than via a proxy but you need root for that. If you have root access the you can use Adaway along with  an updated hosts file from XDA for a stricter ad blocking.( You can add the source location of the hosts file in adaway)

[http://adblock.mahakala.is](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_146943358178414&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=ir1qr4yo01000n4o000MA4a2ck3j8&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D1916098&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fadblock.mahakala.is%2F&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&title=MoaAB%3A%20Mother%20of%20All%20AD-BLOCKING%2006082016%20%26g%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Android%20Development%20and%20Hacking&txt=http%3A%2F%2Fadblock.mahakala.is)

If you don't have root access then you can use adgaurd. But it sets up a vpn. For more effective ad blocking in apps, you should get adguard premium version.

Comment: [Ad Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker) can also be found on F-Droid, if you don't want to risk loading it from some "unknown site". I personally use [AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway) and am quite satisfied with it. As pointed out, it needs root to adjust the hosts file. [AdGuard](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.adguard.android) is also available via the F-Droid client (if you add my repository to it), so you can keep it automatically updated :)

Comment: Will look into adgaurd premium as not rooted. Thanks for the help!